# After upgrading dokku can't start applications

Tags: docker

We just upgraded from docker 0.19 to 0.30. all the docker containers
for services (postgres, redis, etc.) seem to be running again.
but the containers for the apps are missing.

when we start an app with

```
dokku ps:rebuild <appname>
```

everything seems to run fine (build process, ...)
but then it ends with the following error message:

```
-----> Running post-deploy
panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1 goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/dokku/dokku/plugins/common.ParseScaleOutput({0xc00018a200, 0x0, 0xc0000986a0?})
        /go/src/github.com/dokku/dokku/plugins/common/common.go:399 +0x154
github.com/dokku/dokku/plugins/network.BuildConfig({0x7ffd90be32f2, 0x6})
        /go/src/github.com/dokku/dokku/plugins/network/network.go:55 +0x116
main.main()
        /go/src/github.com/dokku/dokku/plugins/network/src/triggers/triggers.go:34 +0x534
!     exit status 2
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug in upgrading from very old versions of Dokku. Folks should check the state of `dokku ps:scale` after upgrading to make sure scale values are set correctly.

See https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/5692 for following up prior to making any changes to your system.

To fix the scale counts, run the following command with the appropriate name and scale values:

```
dokku ps:scale <appname> web=1
```